# Using variables in a reg-ex

Tags: python, regex

So I matched (with the help of kind contributors on stack overflow) the item number in:

```
User Number 1 will probably like movie ID: RecommendedItem[item:557, value:7.32173]the most!
```

Now I'm trying to extract the corresponding name from another text file using the item number. Its contents look like:

```
557::Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea (1961)::Adventure|Sci-Fi
```

For some reason I'm just coming up with 'None' on terminal. No matches found.

```
myfile = open('result.txt', 'r')
myfile2 = open('movies.txt', 'r')
content = myfile2.read()
for line in myfile:
    m = re.search(r'(?<=RecommendedItem\[item:)(\d+)',line)
    n = re.search(r'(?<=^'+m.group(0)+'\:\:)(\w+)',content)
    print n
```

I'm not sure if I can use a variable in a look behind assertion..
Really appreciate all the help I'm getting here!

EDIT: Turns out the only problem was the unneeded caret symbol in the second regular-expression.

Comment: Works here (CPython 2.6.2), what version are you using?
`python example.py

Voyage`

Comment: I have Python 2.7.2...

Comment: Check your input. Your code works for me([Ideone example](http://ideone.com/mD87Gp)).

Comment: Haha I was wondering where your answer disappeared! My input is a file called movies.txt which has a lot of lines like the one I wrote above.

Comment: @Siddhartha, my answer was wrong. There is no differences between `r'\:\:)(\w+)'` and `'\:\:)(\w+)'`.

Comment: IT WORKED! I didn't need the caret symbol "^"

Comment: @Siddhartha, Haha, nice typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, once you've found the number, you use a 'old style' (could equally use `.format` if you so desired) string format to put it into the regular expression. I thought it'd be nice to access the values via a dictionary hence the named matches, you could do it without this though. To get the a list of genres, just `.split("|")` the string under `suggestionDict["Genres"]`.

```
import re
num = 557
suggestion="557::Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea (1961)::Adventure|Sci-Fi"

suggestionDict = re.search(r'%d::(?P<Title>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\s\((?P<Date>\d+)\)::(?P<Genres>[a-zA-Z1-9|]+)' % num, suggestion).groupdict()
#printing to show if it works/doesn't
print('\n'.join(["%s:%s" % (k,d) for k,d in suggestionDict.items()]))
#clearer example of how to use
print("\nCLEAR EXAMPLE:")
print(suggestionDict["Title"])
```

Prodcuing

```
Title:Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea 
Genres:Adventure|Sci
Date:1961

CLEAR EXAMPLE:
Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea 
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Henry for help with both my questions. I got it to work though, just didn't need the caret symbol.

Comment: Sure mate, pleasure to help. What do you mean by carrot symbol though out of interest?

Comment: the "^" symbol that I used in my second reg-ex.